# Data cannot show in view in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel

i create a controller as usual and planning to passing data to view and show, but i don't know why the data cannot be showing, i using dd($statuses) is showing array passed with correct data. but when i change to view the data was disappear, anyone know what is the problems here?

This is my view

```
<div class="col-lg-5">
    @if(!$statuses->count())
        <p>There is no status here</p>
    @else
        @foreach($statuses as $status)
            <p>{{ $status->body }}</p>
        @endforeach
    @endif
</div>
```

My controller

```
$statuses=Status::where(function($query){
            return $query->where('user_id',Auth::user()->id);
                //->orWhereIn('user_id',Auth::user()->friends()->lists('id'));
        })
            ->orderBy('created_at','desc');

        return view('profile.testing')
            ->with('statuses',$statuses);
```

The Code below is used to check whether the data has been passed. The result is array with my correct data so mean my data has passed, but not sure why it cannot show in view.

```
 $statuses=Status::where(function($query){
            return $query->where('user_id',Auth::user()->id);

        })
            ->orderBy('created_at','desc')
            ->get();
        dd($statuses);
        return view('profile.testing')
            ->with('statuses',$statuses);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you made a mistake in your question you don't actually query any data inside your controller as you are missing a the `get()` call.

```
$statuses=Status::where(function($query){
        return $query->where('user_id',Auth::user()->id);
})->orderBy('created_at','desc')
->get(); // Get the data from the DB

return view('profile.testing')->with('statuses',$statuses);
```

Without the `get()` call your controller probably assigns just an instance of the `QueryBuilder` object to the `$statuses` variable passed to your view.

Comment: Hi, the  ->get() is used to check whether the data has been passed, so is not related to my question. The controller side is the actual code.

Comment: That's my point. You need to call ``get()`` in order to get the data from your database. Otherwise you will only pass an object which defines the query. So your ``foreach`` loop has no data to loop over because you did not ask the database for the data - you just prepared a query (command) for the database, but did not actually ask the database to perform the query. The ``get()`` function is the one that actually asks the database for the data.

Comment: ok look like i found the problems, thank for your help. Save a lot of my time.